# Function that gets it's properties

Tags: javascript, function

How can I create a function where it gets it's property?
For example:

```
myfunc = function(){
    alert(this.a + ":" + this.b);
};
myfunc.a = 5;
myfunc.b = 6;
```

The results is 5:6

Comment: `myfunc(5,5)` and `function(a,b)` - Why not use parameters?

Comment: You need to use the name of the function inside the function body to refer the own properties of a function: `alert(myfunc.a + ':' + myfunc.b);`. @KobyDouek Because they are behaving totally diffrent from function's own properties.

Comment: `myfunc.call(myfunc)` - works just fine. It's weird to use the function object for this, but why not?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways. The first, is as others have mentioned is to name the parameters in your function delcaration:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    alert(a + ':' + b);
}

foo('hello', 'world'); // Output "hello:world"
```

---

Another way however is that a variable is available which contains all function parameters, called `arguments`.

```
function bar() {
    alert(arguments[0] + ':' + arguments[1]);
}

bar('hello', 'world'); // Output "hello:world"
```

It should be noted that while it looks like an array, the `arguments` variable is **not** an instance of the JavaScript `Array` object, the only `Array` property available to use with `arguments` is `.length`.

Comment: I edited your answer to include `:` as the OP requested, and voted up.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use `arguments` here. (And no, it's neither an array nor slow). Please just remove that part from your answer.

Comment: @Bergi I never said it is slow - I said there is a small performance factor which *is* true - initialising and populating a variable that wasn't there previously does have a negative impact on performance - even if that is only measurable in microseconds it still exists and it is a good thing to make people aware of it. Also, I felt discussing arguments was needed here, as it is possible OP has poorly phrased a request for a dynamic input/output. Finally - if it's not an array, what is it? It sure looks like a 0-indexed array to me.

Comment: @Scoots Please report what you get from `arguments.pop()` ..?

Comment: @Teemu Ok, it's an object, structured using numerical indices from 0. It meets the criteria of an array (an ordered series), even if it's not of the JavaScript object type Array. I shall update the answer to distinguish this.

Comment: @Scoots It's an [array-like `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). And no, there is no impact on performance, the usage in your example can (and is, in modern JS engines) be optimised to avoid any object instantiation and will perform exactly the same as the named parameters. And no, while the OPs question is indeed poorly phrased, that's a reason to ask for clarification in the comments instead of posting wild guesses as answers.

Comment: @Bergi Thankyou for the clarification - it seems I've been coding based on outdated principles, I shall update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
myfunc = function(){
    alert(this.a + ":" + this.b);
};

myfunc.call({a: 5, b: 6});
```

When you use the call function, the first parameter is your function's `this` and the second parameter is your function. The `call` function just call you function and assign `{a: 5, b: 6}` to `myfunc`'s this.

Comment: No, the second argument to `call` should not be `myfunc`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I am changing it now.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a closure:

```js
var myFunc = (function(a, b) {

  return function() {
    console.log(a + ":" + b);
  }

})(5, 6)

myFunc();
```

This can be expanded via `prototype` to create class like behaviour:

```js
var myFunc = (function () {
    function myFunc(a, b) {
        if (a === void 0) { a = 5; }
        if (b === void 0) { b = 6; }
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    myFunc.prototype.log = function () {
        console.log(this.a + ":" + this.b);
    };
    return myFunc;
}());
var a = new myFunc();
a.log();
new myFunc().log();
new myFunc(1, 10).log();
//ACCESS ATTRIBUTE
console.log("ACCESSING", a.a);
//OVERWRITE ATTRIBUTE
a.a = 11;
//ACCESS ATTRIBUTE
console.log("ACCESSING", a.a);
a.log();
```